# .Net Core seems to max out reading GPIO pin at about 1000 / second. How to go faster?

Tags: python, .net-core, raspberry-pi, gpio, orange-pi

I wrote a C# .Net Core 3.1 app to read pin state changes on the GPIO of an Orange Pi Zero.
I am using the System.Devices.Gpio IoT library.
I am running Armbian Focal (based on Ubuntu 20.04).

I am trying to read the frequency of a square wave signal, which makes a pin on the GPIO rise and fall. So I'm trying to read how many rising (or falling) edges occur in 1 second.

I have tried both polling the pin in a loop, and registering to events/callbacks to pin changes, and I can't seem to read any faster than about 1000 times per second (1 Khz)

Unfortunately, I need to read at least 5000 times per second (and preferably more).

I don't think the limitation is on the hardware side. I think it's the fact that .Net Core runs on top of a CLR which is an extra layer that is slowing things down.

I am looking at writing this portion of the app in Python (I'll leave the rest of the app in C# / .Net Core), but I don't know if it will speed things up? I know Python is sort of the de facto programming language for SBC's nowadays, which is why I'm considering it (lots of community support and samples). But it's an interpreted language. Would it not be slower than C# which is compiled? But then again, maybe Python talks directly to Linux, unlike C# .Net Core which goes through the CLR. Also Python is baked into Ubuntu so maybe that tight integration has some benefits.

I know C would be the quickest, but also the hardest of the languages to write in (other than Assembly). I'm not too familiar with either C nor Python, but I thought Python would have the less steep learning curve.

In summary, my question is: Is there anything I can perhaps do in .Net Core to speed up reading the GPIO? Would perhaps using a third party library instead of System.Devices.Gpio help (I doubt it)? Is the limitation perhaps on the hardware or maybe in Amrbian (Ubuntu) (I doubt it)? Should I even bother trying it in Python or would it be a waste of time and I should go straight to C?

Sorry, I know my question is probably not according to StackOverflow policies. I was just wondering if anyone maybe has had any experience in reading GPIO pin state changes really fast (as in to measure frequency in the KHz range) - on an Orange or Raspberry Pi or something like that...

I'd appreciate any pointers.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried googling this? A quick googling shows people getting upwards of 25MHz at least on the writes. They of course use C or straight up ASM. There also seem to be constraints on how long you can do it before getting forcibly interrupted by hardware. I think your biggest limiter is using libraries instead of directly poking registers.

Comment: Thanks for your comment r_ahlskog. Yes I have seen people reach quite high speeds, mostly on writing to the GPIO - a bit less on the reading side. But I think you're right in the biggest limiter using libraries. I doubt there's anything I can do to speed things up in .Net Core. I'm guessing attempting to do this in Python might also be a waste of time and I should do it in C directly.

Comment: Who knows, maybe the python library (usually written in C) does direct memory manipulations and is faster. Google or quick proof of concept coding sessions will tell you. Just making this part in a different language like python or C shouldn't be too much of a challenge if you know C#, well maybe python because its a slightly different syntax.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Thanks r_ahlskog. I will not be so quick to discount Python then. I will start looking for code samples in Python and benchmark that. If that's not good enough, I will try with C. Sorry, I know my post was very vague. I was just feeling a bit lost. I appreciate your input.

Comment: I haven't tested the speed in polling with the System.Devices.Gpio library, but I do know that interrupt-based reading should reach several khz now. You do need to use the current preview build for this to work, though.

Comment: Thanks PMF. If the incoming square wave's frequency is higher than around 1.1 KHz I start losing events. Probably because .Net Core is not that fast. I was going to try writing the code in Python or preferably C, but at the end we decided to go with a hardware solution: https://swharden.com/wp/2016-10-10-raspberry-pi-rf-frequency-counter/

Comment: When you comment to people, use `@person_nickname` notation that they will got notification.

Comment: By the way, have you checked `gpiomon` report (this shell tool is a part of `libgpiod` project)? This will show actually a maximum that you may achieve in the user space on the specific hardware (but don't forget to collect events in the file in memory, like on tmpfs, rather printing to the screen).

Comment: @0andriy thans for the tip. will do from now on!

Answer (score 0):

Although re-writing the code in a faster language (perhaps Python, definitely C) would have helped, at the end we decided to put a hardware assist in place (as recommended by some on other posts I've read). We are going for [Raspberry Pi RF Frequency Counter](https://swharden.com/wp/2016-10-10-raspberry-pi-rf-frequency-counter/) solution.

Thanks to [@r_ahlskog](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264148/r-ahlskog) and PMF for your inputs however. It's very much appreciated.